# How to find Watson Assistant assistantId

Tags: watson-assistant

Watson instructions don't seem accurate.  They say to "open the assistant settings and click API Details." according to this page: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2?code=node#messagestateless-request

I don't see any of those options in the dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dialog the assistant settings is the 3 dot menu on the related skill.

For Actions (New Watson Assistant) you click on either Draft or Production environment. There is a cog beside the title and you can find the details there.

1. Go to draft or production environment. Click on the cog / wheel.
   [image: draft env]
2. Check for the environment ID:
   [image: details in new Watson Assistant]

If you aren't seeing credentials then you might not have them on your instance. This is done automatically when the instance is created but it is possible for someone to delete them. You will need to create a new service credentials.

If you still have issues then it may be related to the rights you have been given on the cloud account. Speak to the Cloud admin.

Comment: Thanks that helped.  Felt like an expedition to the North Pole just to find this ID.